# why my function call multiple times when right click second time on element?

Tags: javascript

My purpose is when right click show menu selection between delete and copy.
Currently when i right click first time function work good, but when i right click second time and choose any select then will run two times, if i rightclick 3 times i need close form 3 times and so on,...

```
fieldBox.element.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) =>{

  const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  const rect =  fieldBox.element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete');
  const copyButton = document.getElementById('copy');
  const x =  rect.left;
  const y = rect.top;
  menu.style.top = `${y}px`;
  menu.style.left = `${x}px`;
  // show menu
  menu.style.cssText =
                        `display: block;
                        position: absolute;
                        z-index: 1000;
                        padding: 12px 0;
                        width: 70px;
                        background-color: #fff;
                        border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
                        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #cfcfcf;
                        top:${y}px;
                        left:${x}px;
                        color:#327fcb`;

  // remove menu when click somewhere
  document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    
  });

  // handle click menu
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    

    this.handleDeleteFieldBox(fieldBox);
    menu.style.display = 'none';
  
  });

  copyButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const newFieldBox = cloneDeep(fieldBox);
    this.fieldBoxList.push(newFieldBox);
    this.pdfDrawableBox.getContentWrapper().appendChild(newFieldBox.render());
    menu.style.display = 'none';
   
  });
});
```

Comment: You're adding an event listener to your document, delete and copy buttons each time you open the right-click menu. Only do this once. Move that code outside of the contextmenu event listener function, or unbind the event listeners when you close the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you respond to the `contextmenu` event, you're **adding** a further `click` handler (actually, multiple click handlers).

What you're passing `removeEventListener` is not correct. You must pass it the function you passed `addEventListener`. We can't say what `this` in your arrow functions is, but it's not the event listener function.

Here's an example of how to correctly add and remove an event listener, using your `deleteButton` for the example:

```
// *** Remember the function
const deleteButtonHandler = () => {
    console.log('hello delete button clicked')

    this.handleDeleteFieldBox(fieldBox);
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    deleteButton.removeEventListener('click', deleteButtonHandler); // *** Remove it
};
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteButtonHandler); // *** Add it
```

Another approach is to add the handler **once** and use a flag to manage whether it does anything, rather than adding and removing it.